# Cut all symbols between () from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string such as :

```
"Overweek (0000-00-00),Overweek (2017-05-29), Next month (2017-08-01)"
```

And I need to get only string

```
"Overweek,Overweek,Next month"
```

How can I cut `()` symbols and all between them?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove spaces also before comma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression

```js
var str  = "Overweek (0000-00-00),Overweek (2017-05-29), Next month (2017-08-01)"
var str2 = str.replace(/\(.*?\)/g,'');

console.log(str2)
```

If you want to remove all whitespace as well

```
/\(.*?\)|\s/g
```